# Publishing in Shopify Appstore: Do you have to be using their API?

Tags: angular, e-commerce, shopify

So we have built a large platform that integrates completely with Shopify's API. As a result we've signed on hundreds of Shopify brands who have integrated our technology.

Now, we also have a separate influencer marketing tool that we make available to our partner brands. It doesn't involve the Shopify API at all, but it's made available exclusively to Shopify brands and they get a lot of use out of it.

Is it possible to publish into the Shopify appstore with something that doesn't actually use the Shopify API but is a tool for Shopify brands? Trying to use this as a lead generation tactic.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify's App Store only accepts apps that use the Shopify API. You can find more information about the approval criteria here: https://help.shopify.com/api/listing-in-the-app-store/app-review-checklist